# Non rectangular heat source Python

Tags: python

I have to make heat source shaped like X, but it has to be defined as function.
In matrix it would be:

```
Gr=np.eye(10)*5000
for iGr in range(10):
    Gr[iGr,-iGr-1]=5000

def assert_heaters(M, Gr):
    M[20:30,10:20] = np.where(Gr > 0, Gr, M[20:30,10:20])
M=np.zeros([L,B])           
assert_heaters(M, Gr)
```

I tried to make a function, but with no success.

```
def q(x,y,qqq):
    qq=0
    for k in range 10:
        if x>20 and x<30 and y>10 and y<20:

        qq=qqq
    return qq
```

My question is: how can I make it look like X instead of rectangular?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly in the 'q' function? There is nothing after the 'if' (or the qq=qqq is wrongly indented?) Are you trying to simulate the first three lines of the original program?

Comment: q function is kind of a blank function. i dont know how it's supposed to look, so i didnt write anything.
qq=qqq is wrongly indented.

Comment: What is wrong with the reply jedwards gave you here: http://quabr.com/28974818/heat-diffusion-on-a-2d-plate-python?

Comment: that's one way to solve it, i need to use heat as a function. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like (untested):

```
def heat(x, y):
    x1 = x - 20
    y1 = y - 10
    if x1 < 0 or x1 > 9 or y1 < 0 or y1 > 9:    # out of range
        return 0
    if (x1 == y1) or (x1 == 9-y1):
        return 5000
    else:
        return 0
```